Connect react native frontend with Symfony backend
I'm trying to connect a 3 parts application with a symfony backend localhost port 8000 with a web frontend in react localhost port 3000 and a mobile app frontend using expo go and react native.
So far it's just a proof of concept, hello world based. Symfony open up a /hello route returning a json response.
React web frontend use Axios to hit symfony hello route and print the recovered information. This works properly using this in App.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/hello') // Changez le port si nécessaire
        .then(response => setMessage(response.data.message))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
  }, []);

  return (
      <div>
        <h1>{message}</h1>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Now I also want to be able to recover and print that data on my mobile device connecting the expo go and following code. Sadly i'm then getting a network error. This test was made having mobile connected to public wifi and sharing the connection with the pc. So i guess the two were properly connected on that point. But may be private wifi is required ? I also tried adding some debug information and it seems quite obvious the error is about being able for the mobile to find the symfony app of the laptop.

Android Bundled 26ms C:\Users\chris\Desktop\Linkwise\linkwise-mobile\node_modules\expo\AppEntry.js (1 module)
ERROR  Error fetching data: No response received {"DONE": 4, "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2, "LOADING": 3, "OPENED": 1, "UNSENT": 0, "_aborted": false, "_cachedResponse": undefined, "_hasE
rror": true, "_headers": {"accept": "application/json, text/plain, /"}, "_incrementalEvents": false, "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {}, "_method": "GET", "_perfKey": "network_XMLHt
tpRequest_http://localhost:8000/hello", "_performanceLogger": {"_closed": false, "_extras": {}, "_pointExtras": {}, "_points": {"initializeCore_end": 27779116.850546, "initializ
eCore_start": 27778994.710911}, "_timespans": {"network_XMLHttpRequest_http://localhost:8000/hello": [Object]}}, "_requestId": null, "_response": "Failed to connect to /localhost:8000", "_responseType": "", "_sent": true, "_subscriptions": [], "_timedOut": false, "_trackingName": "unknown", "_url": "http://localhost:8000/hello", "readyState": 4, "responseHeaders": undefined, "status": 0, "timeout": 0, "upload": {}, "withCredentials": true}

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/hello') // Changez le port si nécessaire
        .then(response => setMessage(response.data.message))
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
  }, []);

  return (
      <View>
        <Text>{message}</Text>
      </View>
  );
}


Also tried to replace localhost by 127.0.0.1 and also by ipv4 pc url.
Any idea what i'm missing to get react native able to connect with my symfony local application ?
